# Symfony : add star rating system in FOSCommentBundle

Tags: php, symfony, listener, bundle, foscommentbundle

I have spent the last couple days working out a way to make the FOSCommentBundle adhere to my needs but i'm definitly too bad. All my pages needs a "rating" comment system. This will include both the comment body text area and a choice list of 5 stars to rate the content (Question, Tuto, etc...).

Should i use Listenner ?

Should i use PRE_UPDATE event of Doctrine?

If you have any idea, post it here.

Comment: generate rating entity and add one-to-many from comment to rating

Comment: @johnSmith thanks for reply, can you be more specific about generate rating entity ?

Comment: sth. like http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioGeneratorBundle/commands/generate_doctrine_entity.html

Comment: @johnSmith okay, and what about doctrine relation between rating and content?

Comment: sth. like http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-many-self-referencing